# Is Skype delivering off-line messages now?

Tags: skype

as far as I know, for a message in skype to be received by other side. both sender and receiver need to be online at the same time. But recently it seems like this is not the case.

For example a friend sent me a message when I was offline, and then he went offline. when I got online I got the message though he wasn't online at the same time.

also usually, when you block a contact, and that contact keeps sending you messages (thinking you will get them when you become online), you get those messages after you unblock. But this time I blocked someone, and when I unblocked him back I didn't get any of the messages he sent while he was blocked.

why is this happening ? Did Microsoft change the way skype work ?

Comment: This was changed awhile ago, when Messenger was merged into Skype

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recently Skype added cloud messaging. Before recently, Jan/Feb of 2014 (I forgot when exactly, was either at the end of Jan or beginning of Feb), it was a peer-to-peer system, but now on the smartphone age that system just didn't cut it so they are "SLOWLY" changing their system to cloud messaging. It'll be a while before everyone gets the benefit of cloud messaging, but still this year everyone will benefit from the new system and the messages will be delivered whether people are offline or online.